# Looking for a book specifically about the 37 factors of enlightenment

Tags: books

Not sure if this is the correct place to ask this question so sorry if it is not.
I am just looking for a book that is specifically about the 37 factors that explains each one in depth.

Answer (score 1):

> **The Wings to Awakening: An Anthology from the Pāli Canon, by Ṭhānissaro Bhikkhu**. The 37 Wings to Awakening (bodhi-pakkhiya-dhamma) were the Buddha’s own summary of his teachings. This book contains sutta translations organized by topic with relevant discussion by the author. Internal cross-references are hyper-linked in the ebook versions, and in the online version external ones, i.e. to the Suttas, are as well. https://www.dhammatalks.org/books/Wings/Section0001.html

Answer (score 0):

It is inside the path of purification from chapter 14 - chapter 23.

You need to meditate 4th Jhana at mastery level to be a genius one who have professional photographic memory, and you need Abhidhamma knowledge to understand it.

You can also begin with [ven. Pa-Auk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZMdMFm1uL5E).

[Path of Purification (Visuddhimagga) by Ven. Ñāṇamoli](https://www.accesstoinsight.org/lib/authors/nanamoli/PathofPurification2011.pdf)